# Redshift: Short cut to transform column values into a table

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a need to solve an table transformation problem and I am looking for any short cuts in Redshift.

I have a table that contains a unique identity, a property_name, and a property_value as columns:

```
{{uid=1, property_name=A, property_value =AA}, {uid=1, property_name=B, property_value=BB}}
```

I need to transform this into a table where the unique_id and property_names are the columns and populate it with the associated property_values. In the example above the table would be transformed as so:

```
{{uid=1, A=AA, B=BB}}
```

Are there any redshift shortcuts anyone is aware of that would make this as easy as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is uid the same across all columns in the same row? Is the value for property_name the same for all rows in a given column? Some more example data would be useful, it's hard to extrapolate a solution from a single row.

Comment: is `property_name` list known in advance and finite? if so then yes you can do it, unless there is nothing you can do in redshift because you can't generate schema based on data without dynamic sql (which is not supported in Redshift)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but below query looks like a solution to me

```
select uid, property_name + ' = ' + property_value from Your_Table group by uid, property_name , property_value
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for replying. It is not the answer I need although it is a good attempt. I need to create a table where the columns of the table are the property_name values and then populate it with the property_values that are associated with it. In the example above, assume that has many more UIDs and more than one distinct property_name per UID.